# Returning List of Generic Type Objects using Wildcards

Tags: java, generics, collections

Requirement:

- Need my method to return List of one of the two specified objects.
- Need to store the result of the above method as a List of one the two specified objects.

Declared a method which returns a Generic List based on wildcards.
Got the declaration part right, but method call fails.

```
class Z{/*TemplateClass*/}
public class A extends Z{}
public class B extends Z{}
```

Test Class:

```
public List<? extends Z> getGenericList(boolean test){
    if(test){
        List<A> aList = new ArrayList<A>();
        aList.add(new A());
        return aList;
    }
    else{
        List<B> bList = new ArrayList<B>();
        bList.add(new B());
        return bList;
    }
}
```

Here's my requirement. I need something like the below code.

```
List<A> testAList = getGenericList(true);
List<B> testBList = getGenericList(false);
```

Gives me a compiler error.

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from List< capture#1-of ? extends Z > to
>   List< A > Type mismatch: cannot convert from List< capture#2-of ? extends
>   Z > to List< B >

I understand the logic behind this. What if we pass a false and store the returned List of B's as a List of A's which is wrong.
But when I use the below code:

```
List<? extends Z> testList = getGenericList(true);
```

It compiles fine. But it beats my purpose. I'm not able to access the methods in A or B as the testList.get(index) returns Z type objects where I hope to get either A or B.

If my code is absolutely wrong, then any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of [Type Erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)? Why not return a `List<Z>`?

Comment: Got the concept. Original object is preserved. Using Z and typecasting later is one of the solutions. I was wondering if it can be done without the casting part.

Comment: `Z` was just a template I used. It's absolutely empty. All the logic/data I need will be present in either `A` or `B`. How would I access this data without typecasting it to either `A` or `B` if the object is `Z`

Comment: Define the contract in Z.

Comment: Your comments helped me solve my problem. Thanks Elliott.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the result which would make the compiler errors go away but you'd have an unsafe cast which seems like a code smell:

```
List<A> testAList = (List<A>) getGenericList(true);
List<B> testBList = (List<B>)getGenericList(false);
```

Also if the boolean input is not a strict requirement you can do something like this as well:

```
public <T extends Z> List<T> getGenericList(Class<T> klass) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        try {
            list.add(klass.newInstance());
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Yup. Rots. Folks I work for are German Shepherds.
Is there a way to accomplish this without the type casting?

Comment: Selecting this as the answer as it directly answers my question. Even though I used @Elliott's approach to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not going to happen.  You are asking for a type that simply cannot be expressed in the java type system, something like `List<A> + List<B>`.

The closest thing to that is a form of continuation passing style; you create another abstract class like `HomogeneousListAB` with a visitor interface and accept method.  Then you can return one of those from getGenericList.

```
abstract class HomogeneousListAB {
    interface Visitor {
        void ifListA( List< A > la );
        void ifListB( List< B > la );
    }
    abstract public accept( Visitor v );
}

// inside getGenericList true branch
final List< A > laOut = // whatever
return new HomogeneousListAB() {
    public accept( Visitor v ) {
        v.ifListA( laOut );
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 for your approach, though it's a little complicated to grasp at the first look.